# Php / Codeigniter / errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: CodeIgniter error]
Изучаю ПХП и работу на движке CodeIgniter. При открытии сайта на локальном сервере мы ловим сие ошибки. Достаточно ли информации, чтобы пофиксить их и сайт начал открываться?(

Comment: Замените картинку нормальным текстом, это только улучшит читаемость вопроса.

Comment: Какой-то древний код вы пытаетесь запустить на современном php.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать вывод текущих ошибок такими строками:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
```

Должны пропасть ошибки типа `deprecated`. Вместе с ними и предупреждение об изменении заголовков после вывода.

По поводу именно **изучения** PHP на движке **Codeigniter** - время кодигнайтера прошло лет 5-6 назад. Потом был в тренде Yii (первая версия), но и этот тренд канул в лету. Изучая данный движок, Вы заведомо отстаете на два поколения (если так можно выразиться).

Если хотите изучать современные подходы, то **после** изучения основ (нужно **хорошо понимать ООП**) смотрите в сторону Yii**2**, Laravel последних версий, Symfony3. Сейчас это самые популярные фреймворки с развитым комьюнити, т.е. Вы можете быстро найти решение проблемы в гугле. Вместе с этими фреймворками придет и опыт работы с composer'ом.